# Angular mat-table unable to make the cell text ellipsis

Tags: angular, angular-material

Hi i am using angualr material table to for my grid , mat-table internally expands the cell height to adjust the long text , but i want to keep height consistent and show ellipsis instead .

ang suggestion

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

These are the style rules you need (an example):

```
.text-list .ellipsis {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 200px;
}
```

Click to see [a working demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-table-ellipsis).

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem.

What I could find on net was solving the issue but only if using `mat-table` as element (`<mat-table>...</mat-table>`) and not as a directive to the html's `table` element (`<table mat-table>...</table>`).

So if you are using mat-table as element here is a working solution (note that in this case you cannot use some of the html table's element features like `colspan`, `rowspan` and others):
https://stackblitz.com/edit/text-overflow-on-mat-table-using-display-flex-vz5wh7?file=app%2Ftable-basic-flex-example.css

And if you are using mat-table as directive here is what you should do:

1. add this css to the `div` or `span` containing the values that need to be trimmed with ellipsis:

```
    .mat-cell-value {
      text-overflow: ellipsis;
      overflow: hidden;
      white-space: nowrap;
    }
```

2. Add this input to the table element:

   `<table mat-table [fixedLayout] > ... </table>`

This (`[fixedLayout]`)will make all columns the same width, so when resizing the window the columns' widths will resize proportionally as well, and when column's width becomes smaller than its value width, it will trim the value and add ellipsis to the part that can not fit.

I guess this can also be solved by adding percentages to columns' widths (ex: first column-20% second column-50%, third column-10%, fourth column-20%). What is important is that we must somehow specify columns' width because by default mat-table's columns will shrink up to a point where it can contain all the values (so up to the width of the cell that contains the longest value obviously) after that it will stop shrinking and thus ellipsis will not work, in the ways mentioned earlier we are enforcing it to shrink further.